# Python dictionary, extract two values in one iteration

Tags: python, loops, flask

I have a dictionary containing two "repeating" values, one named content the second named time.
This dict is created using a for loop:

```
    loopindex = 1
    thisdict = {}
    for u in Comment.select():
        stringloop = str(loopindex)
        if u.commentId == tempid:
            print('match')
            thisdict.update({"content" + stringloop: u.commentContent})
            thisdict.update({"time" + stringloop: u.timestamp})
        loopindex += 1
```

Doing this i end up with the following output when using print in a for loop (keys, values):

```
content1 This is a comment attempt
time1 2020-01-04 11:28:05.507961
content2 This is a comment attempt
time2 2020-01-04 11:33:05.108815
content3 This is a comment attempt
time3 2020-01-04 11:33:33.153281
content4 This is a comment attempt
time4 2020-01-04 11:34:37.880837
```

I now need to, in a loop, extract one content value and one time value in the same loop iteration.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. You're probably better off by using a list of dict, where each dict has the same keys.

Comment: Instead of creating two items in the dictionary, create one item that is itself a nested dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going the wrong way.
Dicts are not sorted so the output you have is not fixed at all. If more data comes in the output can be all over the place.

I suggest to create the dict differently.

I would do a list of tuple like this:

```
output = []
for u in Comment.select():
    if u.commentId == tempid:
        print('match')
        output.append((u.commentContent,u.timestamp))
```

Access it with `output[i][0]`(content) / `output[i][1]` (timestamp)

or if you want to use a dict instead of a tuple:

```
output.append({"content":u.commentContent,"timestamp":u.timestamp})
```

Access with `output[i]["content"]` / `output[i]["timestamp"]`

Comment: How old is your Python that your dicts aren't ordered?

Comment: I am fully aware that dicts must preserve insertion order from 3.7 on. Before the devs mention it's an implementation detail but should not be relied on. And since I don't know which version he is using it's better to be safe than sorry.